# Need to get error code alone from header and also the json response in MS Dynamics web api in php

Tags: php, dynamics-crm

I'm using `Prefer:return=representation` to get specific fields while creating accounts

**API URL**
`https://xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=accountid,name,telephone1`.

**Request**

```
  $params['firstname'] = $first_name;
  $params['lastname']  = $last_name;   
  $authHeader = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token;
    $headers = array (
            $authHeader,
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Prefer:return=representation', //NEWLY ADDED TO GET SPECIFIC 
  FIELDS
            'Accept:application/json;' 
    );

    $data_string = json_encode ( $params );

     $custom_vars [CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = true;
    $custom_vars [CURLOPT_HEADER] = true; 
    customLogs('case_create.log',print_r($data_string,true),3);
    $result = gUnifyCURLCall ( $url, 'POST', $data_string, $headers, true, false, $custom_vars );

 function gUnifyCURLCall($url, $method_type = 'GET', $data_string = null, $header = null, $ssl_verify = true, 
    $tls_version = false, $custom_vars = array()) {
  $ch = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method_type );
if ($data_string != null) {
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string );
}
if ($header != null) {
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );       
}
if(!empty($custom_vars)) {      
    foreach ( $custom_vars as $key=>$val) {         
        curl_setopt($ch, trim($key), 1);
    }
}

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );

curl_close ( $ch );
return $result;
```

}
I want to get server error code and also the response, so i'm passing `CURLOPT_VERBOSE:TRUE`,`CURLOPT_HEADER:TRUE` in the header. It returns following response from MS Dynamics.

> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST
>   Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
>   Expires: -1
>   Server: 
>   x-ms-service-request-id: 85aed055-abff-42b0-a9bd-a4ad617638b1
>   REQ_ID: 85aed055-abff-42b0-a9bd-a4ad617638b1
>   AuthActivityId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Preference-Applied: return=representation
>   x-ms-ratelimit-burst-remaining-xrm-requests: 5995
>   x-ms-ratelimit-time-remaining-xrm-requests: 1,199.79
>   OData-Version: 4.0
>   Public: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST
>   Set-Cookie: ApplicationGatewayAffinity=69ed338020af0cda5b08cef8314523419f00ed630d46bde35fe61b31f28285cf;Path=/;Domain=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.dynamics.com
>   Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 10:43:48 GMT
>   Content-Length: 244
>   **{"@odata.context":"https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#accounts(accountid,name,fax)/$entity","@odata.etag":"W/\"11660448\"","accountid":"xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx","name":"xxxxxx","fax":"9500293527"}
>   )**

previously we were only working with the response code in the header to get the entity_id,now MS Dynamics web api is updated ,so now we want the response code from header and also the response using PHP

Comment: **Side note:** `201` is not error code by the way. It is a success message saying resource is created.

Comment: yes success message...how can we call this commonly....server response code?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code and we might be able to help. Also, since I'm guessing that you're using cURL, there are thousands of guides/tutorials/questions about how to use it with PHP if you do some research.

Comment: You forgot to post the contents of `gUnifyCURLCall()` which seem to be the function that actually makes the call. Remember that we don't know _anything_ about your code unless you explicitly show it to us.

Comment: i have updated the question now please look into